# How to delete a subprofile?

Tags: support

How do I completely remove myself from Hardware Recommendations? To be clear I want to stay on all the other Stack Exchange sites, except this one?

I do not agree with the current moderation and don't want to waste my time and anyone else's at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [contact us](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer of the site, and select "I need to delete my user profile".

Your account will be added to a deletion queue by the Stack Exchange staff, and will be removed after a period of time, if you don't manually cancel the deletion.